# What is the English word for a “map indicator"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

See this:

[image]

What is the English word for the red markers with a letter on them? 
Google itself seem to use, well, **marker**, but I wonder if that’s too technology-related (like, say, **pointer**?).

I need a word that applies to red markers on the map above, but also  to the real world object, [like this](http://www.midwesternmac.com/sites/midwesternmac.com/files/location-marker.png): in other words, something with a pin that is literally placed on a map to indicate a point.

Thought about **pin** itself, **pinpoint**, but I am not sure about which is the best.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, nice first question

Comment: They're *[virtual] map **pins***. They even *look* like real-world [map pins](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=picture+map+pins&hl=en&biw=1164&bih=717&tbm=isch&imgil=0riCdlCCNCw1YM%253A%253BaHYOwjqOHvdDzM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.123rf.com%25252Fphoto_7878756_map-pins-in-colors-red-green-and-blue.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=0riCdlCCNCw1YM%253A%252CaHYOwjqOHvdDzM%252C_&usg=__F5Tde8pOhn7EGLDt8TrbUPRxu7o%3D&ved=0ahUKEwjWsvSEisDKAhXBWRQKHd33BLgQyjcIRA&ei=SoWjVtblIsGzUd3vk8AL#imgrc=0riCdlCCNCw1YM%3A)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have come to agree with you on **map pin**. I’ll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @m vai: Peter posted ***pin*** in his answer at the same time as I posted my comment. And it's a *good* answer because the implication of giving several alternatives is that this isn't a situation where every native speaker knows perfectly well what those things are called (and where everyone agrees on the *same* name). In practice, I suspect many people (if they unavoidably found they *had* to refer to one in a conversation, say) would just call it a *thingamajig, thingy, doofer, doodah, whatyemacallit, whatsit,* etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ok, thanks. I’m not used to ELL and I have to say it feels kinda strange to *choose* among different answers the one that fits *my* needs. This is completely unusual on, say, Stack Overflow, where in most cases there’s one and only solution to the question, and it’s easy to look at an answer and say “oh, he definitely solved it”.

Comment: @m vai: I guess the problem here is there's no real consensus on whether questions like yours are best answered by citing *dictionary definitions* (an approach which fits with the SO model of *providing authoritative references*) or by people with broad exposure to actual usage saying what they think native speakers *tend* to say in the specified context. Consider [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79105/a-word-for-getting-colored?noredirect=1#comment154014_79105), for example. What good is it to the OP to know a word that hardly anyone actually uses, even if it's "right"?

Comment: I'm a native speaker (AmE) and in fifteen or so years I have never referred to those red bubble thingies by any name at all. I know their function. I would probably just refer to what they refer to, namely locations on a map or returns of a search. I would not use map pin or pushpin because they are real world objects. I might say virtual pushpin or virtual map pin, but I doubt it. Thus, what name would I give those things. See my first sentence.

Comment: @GoDucks I probably was not clear enough in my question, about the fact that I needed a word which would fit *both* the virtual balloons and the physical object. I’m not a native speaker but I feel that **map pin**, even if used in a totally different context, reminds of the real world object. In the mean time, while looking at a google map, you can probably say **map pin** and be understood. That is exactly what I was looking for. I can relate to the fact that the *virtual balloons* alone do not have a proper name - it’s the same in my language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get you point. As an asker, I would probably indicate which kind of answer I am really looking for.

Comment: @m vai: I think GoDucks summed up the "real-world" situation for the average native speaker. Very likely there are a number of software libraries out there with specific functions/methods that handle the "software objects". I don't know whether it would be considered On Topic to ask on the SO programming site how those functions are usually *named* in code, but I wouldn't bet on them being called "map_pins". On the other hand, if you want to reference both the physical and the virtual versions with the same term, I think you pretty much *have* to use the physical term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google themselves use **pin** to select a location: **dropped pin**

The **red bubbles** are **location indicators** or **location tags** acting as **locators** to mark geographic **points**.

**Locator** is possibly the **single word** you're looking for to call the red bubbles.

> Each **locator** on the map points to a location of interest.

Comment: You are right about Google, they use **marker** only in their developer libraries (I’m a developer). As for **locator**, I personally don’t like it. I mean, if you are in a different context and you say **locator**, no one is going to think of [this object](http://marketingland.com/wp-content/ml-loads/2014/08/local-search-map-pin-ss-1920.jpg), right?

Comment: Fair enough, but that's a picture of a pushpin(!) If you had a caption "the locators show the points of interest" for [this](http://www.mmaonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/iStock_000009008402XSmall_Map_Push_Pins.jpg), I bet people would figure out what the **locators** are.  Without a picture, the reader will look for **something that indicates a location** not for a specific **indicator**

Comment: I think that “pin", "map pin" or “pushpin" can be what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: **Pin** is generic as is **map pin**, **pushpin** is a specific object which would not be confused with the red bubble thingy. Glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, the best word choice would be just ''**balloon mark**" or "**balloon pointer**".

It would be simple and uncomplicated and would be easy to say also.

Comment: I think "balloon marker" might be better. A [marker](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/marker) is an object or sign that shows the position of something. A [mark](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mark) has a more general meaning as a symbol made to indicate something.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, it's the **'Google Maps *pin*'**,  that

> "teardrop-shaped marker icon including a shadow"

which is part of its description found in the patent for the very thing you ask about. See Wikipedia on the [Google Maps pin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps_pin).

I note that the article says

> The Google Maps pin has been called "a product of *pure function* that has evolved into a cultural phenomenon,"

which assuages my predilection for referring more to its function than its name. At least now I know what to call it, as before I was thinking just to say 'red bubble thingy' or 'red balloony thingy'.

Thus if pressed, I can call it a pin, map pin or pushpin:

> pushpin
>
> a thumbtack with a spherical or cylindrical head of colored plastic, used to fasten papers to a bulletin board or to indicate positions on charts and maps

(definition found simply by googling for 'push pin define')

It's a more generic term than map pin (which I wouldn't use) and more pleasing than any such overlong term as location indicator, position locator, etc.

Although *virtual tear dropped red balloony GPS/map indicator position-location marker thingy* might work. ;)

Comment: "which assuages my predilection for"? I'm all for not dumbing down our writing, but I think that's pretty advanced vocabulary for this sort of question. You might want to do a quick review with your target audience in mind. I know sometimes I lose the big picture after I spend some time working on a post, so I'm trying to be helpful here, not critical.

Comment: No problem for me specifically, I just learned a new word. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase **indicating balloon** is okay because the indicator is very much like a balloon (balloon shaped).

Comment: An "indicating balloon" is most commonly used to refer to a particular part of a medical device that shows some information about pressure when the balloon appears inflated or deflated (at least in AmE). I would probably say just "indicator" instead of indicating balloon.