# Verbs for describing the action of defecating

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

Is there any verb for describing the action of making shit?

I think *making shit* could be a possible option, but I have never seen it used.

I would like to confirm my assumption and to know other options. As a foreign learner, it is not likely I'll learn these kinds of expressions from textbooks. I know poo is similar, but poo should be a verb without an object. For example, *pooing a shit* may be incorrect because I have never seen it being used this way.

I know there is also another word beginning with *d*, but it is a formal and medical one while I seek a colloquial expression.

Comment: "to shit," or more commonly, "to take a shit."

Comment: Defecate ( http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defecate ) is the more proper word for the body function, and feces (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feces ) for what has been passed. S**t has a definite vulgar connotation.

Comment: @JimReynolds It is not an easy question and should be discussed on Meta I guess. The thing is there are too many words and idioms (too broad) and people use their own preferred expressions. The Original Poster must have dictionaries that can translate his/her native language (word) to English and I think  it is off-topic unless specific concern is identified.

Comment: A question is not off-topic simply because a native speaker is able to Google an answer. I think it should be re-opened and that maybe we were too quick to close it because "making a shit" isn't something we like to talk about.

Comment: @ColleenV The Original Poster is asking "Is there any verb for describing the action of making shit?" It's as much off-topic as a question, "Is there any verb for putting food into the mouth and chew"?

Comment: @Rathony I don't think that's clearly off-topic just because it's easy for someone who already knows English to think of an answer. The question is asking for a transitive verb in a colloquial expression. Can you point me to the dictionary that will tell you that if you don't already know an expression similar to the one you're looking for?

Comment: @Rathony I don't see this question as different from http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/80329/9161 or http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/79575/9161 which have been left open. I think we just don't like to talk about shit so we're uncomfortable with the question when the person asking it doesn't know the proper [euphemisms](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/euphemism).

Comment: I was wrong of the word with a f initial, the formal synonym of making a shit. It is defecate.

Comment: Rathony thank you for the comment. I am looking for the USA expression. I hope my explanation nerrow it down.

Comment: Sorry for posting this controversial question. It is a serious question. Maybe I can avoid the uncomfort by replacing SHIT by a firmal alternative to make it sounds serious, which is a synonym I dont know yet.

Comment: ColleenV thank you for your comment. I googled again. Maybe feces is a possible alternative for shit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Jim's answer here includes informal usage, I'd say in a more formal or delicate setting, you could use:

> To answer nature's call

Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/the-call-of-nature

Answer (score 5):

> Take a shit
>
> Take a crap
>
> Take a dump
>
> Pinch a loaf. (This is less common, and is intended to carry a humorous tone.)

And as came up in an ELL chatroom pursuant to this post:

> Dropping off the Browns at the Superbowl.

These phrases are considered vulgar by some, or can be taken as offensive by some people or in some situations.

We often speak of the act less directly to make its utterance less unpleasant to some.

For example, we might use a euphemism, and then append information to make what we mean clearer or more specific:

> I need to {go to the bathroom | use the restroom} and, you know, it's going to take awhile.

Some of the most common euphemisms are used with children. Using them with adults can carry some of the innocent connotation and be less offensive than other terms:

> To go {poo | poo poo | caca | stinky}
>
> To go number two
>
> To {have|make} a {bowel movement | BM} or To move one's bowels

Bowel movement is a medical term, and so carries a less coarse connotation than some other terms, even more so when its common abbreviation is used.

The more technical and formal term is *to defecate.*